# Which AWS RDS instance size (RAM) supports a dataset with 100 GB?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a dataset of 100GB and I want to use AWS (RDS MySQL).

I would like to understand what the minimum required amount of RAM to upload the dataset and later perform the queries.

It is quite expensive to start an instance RDS MySQL with RAM close to 100Gb. If there's a way to work with an instance with smaller amount of RAM, I would like to hear from you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases keep their data on disk (using Amazon Elastic Block Store volumes). You can easily add 100GB of disk storage to *any* Amazon RDS instance.

Databases use RAM for *processing* data and for keeping often-used data in memory ('cache'). More RAM generally improves the performance of a database, but the amount of RAM you need is not related to the amount of data that is being *stored* in the database.

Start with a small RDS instance and, if your queries run too slow, change it to an instance type that has more RAM and CPU.

Comment: In fact I would like to know a way to have a guess of which instance could help me in this task. In my needs I cannot try by chance. I need to be more precisely as  possible. Is there a way to estimate?

Comment: Every application is different. Nobody can tell you the system size you require. The correct method to size the system would be to create a Test system and simulate typical usage. You can then measure your app and database and adjust it as necessary to achieve suitable performance. Then, apply these learnings to your production system.

Comment: That's ok! I got The point, @John Rotenstein.  Thanks for sharing